# Needed more information about Paypal Notify URL

Tags: paypal

How paypal run the url that is specified in the notify_url? 
Am i able to get session in that notify_url which is created at the time of checkout in the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass session data to your notify URL (which is an IPN solution) you would need to either send that data in the custom parameter of your button or API request string, or you could save all of the data in a database record, then send the ID of the database record in the custom parameter.

That way the custom parameter will again have that same value within your IPN script so you can easily pull it back out of your database for processing.